# How to define starting grid position on Leaflet's TileLayer?

Tags: leaflet, tile, bounding-box, wms

My app needs to show a map within a box defined by

```
    const corner1 = L.latLng(5.21244812011719, -96.5979537963867);
    const corner2 = L.latLng(34.086555480957, -55.4220504760742);

    const map = L.map(el,
      {
        crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326,
        center: [19.6875, -76.201171875],
        zoom: 3.5,
        maxBounds: new L.latLngBounds(corner1, corner2),
      });
    L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/wms?", {
        layers: 'xxx',
        tileSize: 700,
        transparent: true,
        maxBounds: new L.latLngBounds(corner1, corner2),
        bounds: new L.latLngBounds(corner1, corner2)
      }).addTo(map)
```

The thing is that the layer is requesting the tiles starting outside the borders defined (for example, this request was made http://localhost:8080/wms?&service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=Mano%3AT22&styles=&format=image%2Fjpeg&transparent=true&version=1.1.1&maxBounds=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&time=2018-05-02T00%3A00%3A00.000Z&width=700&height=700&srs=EPSG%3A4326&bbox=-87.71484375,28.4765625,-56.953125,59.23828125 the bbox was **-87.71484375, 28.4765625, -56.953125, 59.23828125**, this contains the corners defined by me but is not optimal as it is requesting a map area that is not going to be seen on my app)

I need that leaflet request tiles that do not exceed the corners defined. How can I archieve that? Thanks in advance

Comment: What was the map current zoom and (approximate) position, and viewport size when you got such request? Looks like you may have been seeing more than your defined bounds, and IIRC Leaflet has to fetch whole tiles, which may extend outside your bounds at low zoom.

Comment: It is on the code posted on the question. When looking at TileGrid code in order to see how it calculates Tiles positions it calculates them by using crs starting position, and that is what I need to change